# Using Super Mario to help me understand Objective C, is this correct?

Tags: objective-c, oop, object

I am a complete newbie when it comes to programming, I've focus most of my youth on design, CSS/HTML and finally decided that I should take the leap to programming.

I've been reading Stephen Kochan's book "Programming in Objective C", I'm about 4 chapters in and wanted some clarification on the concepts of Object Oriented Programming. More or less the concepts of Objects, Classes, and methods using game development as an example.

So if we use Super Mario Bros as an example, disregarding the fact that the game was most likely not developed using Objective C.

From my understanding...

So if "piranha plant" was the class...
Would a chomping piranha plant and fire spitting piranha plant both be objects of that class (piranha plant)?

Would you then apply methods to those objects like:

Chomping Piranha Plant (object):
Raising up/down from pipe
Bites

Fireball Piranha Plant (object):
Raising up/down from pipe
Shoots Fireballs

...?

Am I completely misunderstanding this concept?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds about right. You may want to learn about subclasses, too, and in the case of Objective-C also "protocols".

Comment: No, objects in a game are often mapped to objects in OO programming terminology, but that's not exclusive.

Comment: @Thilo And message sends, dynamism & reflection, class extensions and categories, properties, reference counted memory management, and before all, **C.**

Comment: @H2CO3: Depends if he wants to learn OOP concepts or practical Objective-C. For the former, memory management details and low-level C may be a distraction.

Comment: This is the most rudimentary example of OOP, just trying to understand the concepts between a class and object - than applying methods to those classes. I haven't looked into memory management, properties, etc - as I will be soon... I just wanted to make sure I was on the right track with the relationship between classes & objects. They keep using cars as examples, but that was a little confusing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chomping and Fire-spitting piranha plants are specializations or refinements of the basic piranha plant; they would most likely be subclasses. A subclass can do everything the superclass can do, but has some special tricks of its own.

Since both these types move themselves up and down in their pipes, that would be a method on the base piranha plant class; this is behavior that *all* pirahna plants share. Whatever weird thing they do once they pop up might also be a method on the parent class, which would be overridden by each child class, something like this:

```
@interface PiranhaPlant : NSObject
// Declare properties, other methods...

- (void) ascendFromPipe: (NSRect)pipeFrame;
- (void) doThingThatIDoOnceFullyExtended;
@end

@implementation

//...

- (void) ascendFromPipe: (NSRect)pipeFrame
{
    // ...drawing/animation stuff

    [self doThingThatIDoOnceFullyExtended];
    [self descendIntoPipe];
}

- (void) doThingThatIDoOnceFullyExtended
{
    return;
}

//...
@end
```

---

```
@interface FireSpittingPiranhaPlant : PiranhaPlant
@end

@implementation FireSpittingPiranhaPlant

- (void) doThingThatIDoOnceFullyExtended
{
     [self spitFireball];
}

@end
```

And likewise for other subclasses.

You would then instantiate individual piranha plants, of whichever class, to populate individual pipes. They would each behave according to their class's definition -- one chomps, one spits fire, one jumps entirely out of the pipe and chases Mario around.